# Matlab - Extracting column names using regular expressions

Tags: regex, matlab

I'd like to extract column names from a string using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).
**Note**: The string shown below is only a small part of the actual string I'm searching through.

```
'"column_names":["Date","Open","High","Low","Last","Close","Total Trade Quantity","Turnover (Lacs)"]'
```

I've done some basic operations with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) like searching for dates (etc.), but this one is still too complex for me. This is what I have so far:

```
regexp(string,'(?<="column_names":[")
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: In this example, what would exactly be your desired result(s)?

Comment: What kind of engine does Matlab use? Got a link?

Comment: @LuisMendo Each column name should be extracted as a single string, like this: ``Date``,``Open``,``High``,``Low``,``Last``,``Close``,``Total Trade Quantity``, ``Turnover (Lacs)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a new enough version of Matlab you can use the simpler and faster [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html):

```
strsplit(string(18:end-1),'","')
```

which returns

```
ans = 

  Columns 1 through 6

    'Date'    'Open'    'High'    'Low'    'Last'    'Close'

  Columns 7 through 8

    'Total Trade Quantity'    'Turnover (Lacs)"'
```

If you don't have `strsplit`, the next easiest (and also fast) option is [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
out = textscan(string(18:end-1),'%s','Delimiter','","','MultipleDelimsAsOne',true)
out{:}'
```

You can also use something like `strfind(string,'":["')` to obtain the index of the start of the array in the case that it doesn't always begin with `'"column_names"'`.

*EDIT*: For completeness, here's a regular expression that should work on the whole string (it assumes that your column names can contain word characters (letters, digits, underscore), spaces, and parentheses):

```
out = regexp(string,'(?!^")"([\w\s\(\)]+)"','tokens');
[out{:}]
```

Or you could use just this if you trim the string:

```
out = regexp(string(18:end-1),'[\w\s\(\)]+','match')
```

Comment: Very elegant, but I'm really looking to implement it with ``regexp``.

Comment: @Bluebox: It can be done, but there seems to be no reason. And `regexp` is many many times slower in Matlab. I'll play around.

Comment: I thought that ``regexp`` was pretty fast. Hm, ok...if I'm wrong there, then there really is no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ``regexp``solution! Unfortunately I can't upvote twice..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strtok`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html):

```
str = '"column_names":["Date","Open","High","Low","Last","Close","Total Trade Quantity","Turnover (Lacs)"]'

names = {};
remain = str;
while ~isempty(remain)
    [name remain] = strtok(remain,'"[],:');
    if ~isempty(name)
        names{end+1} = name;
    end
end
```

Result:

```
>> names

names = 

    'column_names'    'Date'    'Open'    'High'    'Low'    'Last'    'Close'    [1x20 char]    'Turnover (Lacs)'
```

Comment: A very good solution, thank you...but I'm really looking for a solution with ``repexp``.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with 2 regexes.
(I'm just guessing the indexing of Matlab arrays)  -

```
 namesStrs = regexp( str, '(?<="column_names":\[)[^\]]+(?=\])', 'match' )
 for k = 1:length(nameStrs)
    disp(nameStrs(k))
    colsStrs  = regexp( namesStrs(k), '(?<=").*?(?=")', 'match' )
    for n = 1:length(colStrs)
       disp(colStrs(n))
    end
 end
```